# MySQL return parent value even if child value doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I'm working with word translation tables (word and word_translate). I need to receive the **id_word** field even if there is not child row... but part of the problem is that i'm already filtering one of the child table's column in the WHERE statement.

I have 2 tables:

1. **word**: id_word, lang, word
2. **word_translate**: id_translate, id_word, lang, word

If I search for a word translation that exists (gato, from spanish to english):

```
SELECT
word.id_word AS id_word,
word_translate.id_translate AS id_translate
FROM word LEFT JOIN word_translate ON word_translate.id_word = word.id_word
WHERE word.lang = "es" AND word_translate.lang = "en" AND word.word = "gato"
```

It returns:

- **id_word** = 72
- **id_translate** = 17

But, if I search for a word translation that doesn't exist (gato, from spanish to portuguese):

```
SELECT
word.id_word AS id_word,
word_translate.id_translate AS id_translate
FROM word LEFT JOIN word_translate ON word_translate.id_word = word.id_word
WHERE word.lang = "es" AND word_translate.lang = "pt" AND word.word = "gato"
```

It returns an *empty* result.

I need it to return:

- **id_word** = 72
- **id_translate** = ***NULL***

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42c344/1).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the logic from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT
    w.id_word AS id_word,
    wt.id_translate AS id_translate
FROM word w
LEFT JOIN word_translate wt
    ON wt.id_word = w.id_word AND wt.lang = 'en'
WHERE
    w.word = 'gato' AND
    w.lang = 'es';
```

Note: You may leave the restrictions on the `word` table, which appears on the left side of the join, in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Works great. Here's the final test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42c344/2 Thanks!